# "build" folder doesn't work alone outside of Node.js project folder

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I have difficulty running my SvelteKit app from a 'build' folder.

When I type `npm run build` in VS Code, it creates the 'build' output folder. Then when I navigate to the build folder (`cd build`) and run the app from there (`node index.js`) the app works.

But if I copy the build folder out of the project's root folder and save it on the desktop, it doesn't work when I run the `node index.js` command.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Isn't a build folder self-contained? Why doesn't it work outside of the project folder?

Comment: which adapter are you using?

Comment: @sveltejs/adapter-node

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that for running app from build folder I need node_module folder and package.json file next to build folder.
That's an unfortunate behavior, because I expected that all dependencies are bundled into the build folder, and build folder itself is self-contained. Moreover, I expected treeshaking technique in bundling used modules - only those modules that are used in my code should be included as dependencies in build folder. And because my build folder is my app's starting point, I definetely did not expect that app will look up for dependencies in the parent folder (outside of build folder)

At least they could add that option - to build solution as a self-contained package or only build a core app

Comment: You pretty much never bundle server-side dependencies, there generally is no need to. (On deployment `npm install` is supposed to be run to get all dependencies installed.)

Comment: I would argue that. I am coming from C#, Asp.Net environment, and there all dependencies are icluded in publish output folder. I expect that build folder is a fully functional app folder, that may run without any server configurations on any machine where node.js installed.

Comment: Without including dependencies vital for app functionality I may face some difficulties. That means if later I update my dependencies in my dev environment and rebuild the project, then I have to update dependencies on the server either before deploying my updated build. That would be fine if you deploy on vercel, netlify, or aws, but will be a pian if you building an enterprise app for internal network without internet (intranet). For the same reason I do not use CDNs - I expect my app to be a fully self-contained package